# How can I make more than edits show in my review notification?

Tags: support, review, review-queue

My review notification only shows `suggested edits`, however I have seen screenshots of other users desktops that have hundreds of notifications here.

Can I add more queue's to my notifications, rather than just edits, or is it something that is based on my rep ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you pass the 10k reputation  mark and unlock the [moderator tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege, the number will stop showing only the suggested edits, but instead show the - almost - total number of all available possible reviews.

For more details, you can check the following question/answers: [What does the number next to the review link in the top bar actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251659/what-does-the-number-next-to-the-review-link-in-the-top-bar-actually-mean)

Comment: 10K, that sucks, it would be so use full users at our level to see that notification, it seems such a small trivial thing to lock behind 10k.

Comment: Honestly @mark the number becomes useless past 10k. We all know there is tons of stuff to review, it really means nothing anymore. At least it showes you something you can take action on..